# Unable to install top2vec

Tags: python, pip, topic-modeling

I'm trying to install `top2vec` for my topic analysis project. To install, I've used this command `pip install top2vec`. The installation process starts normally but it ends with this error:

```
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  exit code: 1

  [8 lines of output]
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
    File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
    File "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-grwckgy_\numba_5149fd90a1d24717819bfa776cf85678\setup.py", line 51, in <module>
      _guard_py_ver()
    File "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-grwckgy_\numba_5149fd90a1d24717819bfa776cf85678\setup.py", line 48, in _guard_py_ver
      raise RuntimeError(msg.format(cur_py, min_py, max_py))
  RuntimeError: Cannot install on Python version 3.11.1; only versions >=3.7,<3.11 are supported.
  [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

Encountered error while generating package metadata.

See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

My `pip` version is: `pip 22.3.1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error your paste tell you everything:

```
File "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-grwckgy_\numba_5149fd90a1d24717819bfa776cf85678\setup.py", line 48, in _guard_py_ver
      raise RuntimeError(msg.format(cur_py, min_py, max_py))
  RuntimeError: Cannot install on Python version 3.11.1; only versions >=3.7,<3.11 are supported.
```

The root cause is when `top2vec` try to install its dependency `numba`, it said it can only support `version >=3.7, <3.11`, while your python version is `3.11.1`.

See [this](https://numba.discourse.group/t/can-not-install-numba-and-llvmlite-to-python-3-11/1651) and [this](https://pythonspeed.com/articles/upgrade-python-3.11/):

> We have not released numba and llvmlite for python3.11. The new python version is requiring massive changes to numba because of how numba is tightly coupled to Python’s bytecode internals.

> The Python 3.11 support for the Numba project, for example, is still a work-in-progress as of Dec 8, 2022. Apparently it took them 6 months post-release until they had Python 3.9 support, and 3 months after 3.10.

So, you can monitor [this official issue](https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/8304) to see their update, or downgrade your python version.

Comment: It's an embarrassing mistake from my side to not read the error text properly even though I'm new in python. Thanks a lot.