# Installing top2vec package, particularly in H2O Notebooks, and the error

Tags: python, package, incompatibility, h2o.ai, top2vec

After installing python top2vec package in H2O notebooks (!pip install top2vec), I am getting the following error when importing top2vec:

```
import top2vec

ValueError: numpy.ndarray size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 96 from C header, got 88 from PyObject
```

I tried the techniques used in https://github.com/MaartenGr/BERTopic/issues/392 and also [Unable to install top2vec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75045575/unable-to-install-top2vec), but none of them were helpful. It looks it is incompatible with numpy package. Any help on how to tackle the error in H2O environment much appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be that `gensim` is compiled against different version of `numpy`. I would try to recompile `gensim` (something like `pip install --force-reinstall --ignore-installed --no-binary :all: gensim`) or change the `numpy` version to the one that was there before the `top2vec` was installed.

Comment: Thanks Tomas, as you mentioned, the problem might be with gensim and numpy versions and comaptibility. I tried pip install --force- ... but not worked for me.